# What is the proper replacement for scipy.interpolate.interp1d?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, interpolation

The class [scipy.interpolate.interp1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) has a message that reads:

> Legacy
>
> This class is considered legacy and will no longer receive updates. This could also mean it will be removed in future SciPy versions.

I'm not sure why this is marked for deprecation, but I use it heavily in my code to return an interpolating function, which `numpy.interp()` does not handle. What is the proper replacement for `scipy.interpolate.interp1d`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> interp1d is considered legacy API and is not recommended for use in new code. Consider using more specific interpolators instead.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/interpolate/1D.html#legacy-interface-for-1-d-interpolation-interp1d

it is asking to:

*Consider using more specific interpolators instead*

---

It also says

> The ‘cubic’ kind of interp1d is equivalent to make_interp_spline, and the ‘linear’ kind is equivalent to numpy.interp while also allowing N-dimensional y arrays.

> Another set of interpolations in interp1d is nearest, previous, and next, where they return the nearest, previous, or next point along the x-axis. Nearest and next can be thought of as a special case of a causal interpolating filter.

Comment: So according to this what would be the specific interpolator that replaces the default linear interpolation of `scipy.interpolate.interp1d`? As I said, `numpy.interp()` does not return a function

Comment: I am afraid document is asking to use `numpy.interp()` for linear and `scipy.interpolate.make_interp_spline()` for cubic.

Comment: Your previous comment was correct, I believe that using `scipy.interpolate.make_interp_spline` with `k=1` is equivalent to the linear interpolator in `interp1d`. Thank you!

Comment: Why is interp1d legacy? What's the problem with it?